# Lme function Error in getGroups.data.frame(dataMix, groups) : invalid formula for groups

Tags: r, error-handling, statistics, lme4

I am fitting a model to do my statistics on the FCR, ADG and ADFI of pigs per treatment, with batch and block as fixed effects without any random effects. Treatment, batch and block are factors, FCR is numeric.

The model looks like this:
fcr_model <- lme(fcr ~ treatment + block + batch, data = data).
I get the error:
"Error in getGroups.data.frame(dataMix, groups)". I do not understand why, can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really fitting a model without any random effects, you should use `lm()` rather than `lme()`: `lme()` can't handle models without random effects.